# Passing parameter from View to Controller MVC using Ajax helper

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Iam trying to pass parameters from the view to controller using the Ajax helper but i dont know what i am missing, i cant get it working!!!

here is the code:

In the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult InsertEvent(int? id)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

The View:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <hr />
    @Ajax.ActionLink(item.First_Name +" "+ item.Last_Name, null, null, new { id = item.Id },
        new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnBegin = "FillName('"+ item.First_Name+ "', '"+item.Last_Name+"')"

    }, new { @class = "clickOnCostumer", @href="#"});
}
```

can anyone help please? i look over many tutorials and they are showing the same solution.. am i missing something?

here is a pic of the debugg
it seems all is good but its not returning the value to the controller:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to properly set the controller and `InsertEvent` function in the @ActionLink arguments.

Comment: they are, i used the debugger to check if they are set together and they are working. the think is that am getting no value of the id in the controller.. @Partick Steadman

Comment: Unclear what you trying to do. What is your `FillName()` function. What is your `clickOnCostumer()` function. Why have you set `href="#"` (which wont call the `InsertEvent()` method. And since you have not specified the `UpdateTargetID` ajax option, what are you expecting to do with this code?

Comment: those have nothing with my issue to do, @Stephen Muecke. the fillName() is a function that fills the form input automatically after user click on ActionLink, the clickOnCostumer is nothing.. just drop it. UpdateTargetId is not going to help in this case..

Comment: @moji, Nothing in the code you have shown makes sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: go for jquery ajax rather than @Ajax.ActionLink that is more simple

Answer (score 0):

Two things;

Avoid sending multiple calls to the controller inside a loop. That's a major performance issue.
Use Jquery get method. It's simple and easy to use. Here is an example.

```
@model Models.MyList2
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    string allIndexes = "";

    if (Model.Any())
    {
        allIndexes = string.Join(",", Model);
    }
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.get("\MyController\MyMethod", { variablename: '@allIndexes' }, function(result) {
            $("#anotherinput").val(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Add a if condition to jquery to check if @allIndexes is empty. Change your controller to accept a comma separated list. If you need you can have an IENumerable parameter in your controller. But in that case, you will have to construct your array in jquery. It can be done. But it needs a bit more coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the URL value of the [AjaxOptions object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions(v=vs.118).aspx), or consider if the arguments of the [ActionLink method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).asp) are being used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: item.First_Name +" "+ item.Last_Name, 
             actionName: "InsertEvent", 
             routeValues: new { id = item.Id }, 
             ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
             {
                 HttpMethod = "GET",
                 OnBegin = "FillName('"+ item.First_Name+ "', '"+item.Last_Name+"')"
             }, 
             htmlAttributes: new { @class = "clickOnCostumer", @href="#"})
```

It might help to explicitly detail which part is for each parameter. Also you might need to add the InsertionMode under the ajaxOptions. For example in what I needed in my code, I had to do a replace, so I had to add in, where the updateTargetId is the div enclosing my html:

```
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                 UpdateTargetId = "rightPanelContent"
```